# More functions in one controller /something/something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently when adding a controller it has ex. /dashboard/index
How can i implementate /dashboard/editaccount ex? How can i "render" template for this (view)?

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
     u = Users.find(session[:id])
     @username = u[:username]
  end

  def editaccount
     ##Some code??
  end
end
```

I am completly new in ruby on rails, so hope you can answer me beginner question.

Answer (score 1):

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  def index
     user = Users.find(session[:id])
     @username = user[:username]
  end

  def edit_account
    # Your code
    # automatically renders the 'edit_account' template
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
resource :dashboard do
  get 'edit_account', on: :collection
end
```

Learn more on [**Routing** in the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Please be aware that I changed the naming of your `DashboardController` to `DashboardsController`. It's customary to name controllers in Rails in plural, even when using singular routes (see the Rails guides link above and search for **singular resources**).